# Arrange the data table in R based on clash of dates

Tags: r, dplyr

please find the data table created in R. I want to sort the data in such a way that for a particular patient, say "Moon" or "Son", wherever clash of the date occurs, I want the corresponding activities to be arranged in ascending alphabetic order. Just for illustration, if you see the first three rows, it should be "handling" column values starting with B,C,D and not B,D,C. Please help.

```
pt1 <- read.table(
text = "
handling          patient   time             Sorting
B_Registration    Moon      2017-02-01       10
D_Triage          Moon      2017-02-01       20
C_Performa        Moon      2017-02-01       15
A_Form            Son       2017-02-07        5
Operation2        Moon      2017-02-03       25
D_Triage          Son       2017-02-01       20
A_Form            Moon      2017-02-01        5
C_Performa        Son       2017-02-07       15
Operation2        Son       2017-02-04       25
B_Registration    Son       2017-02-04       10
",
 header = TRUE,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: dplyr::arrange(pt1, time, handling)

Answer (score 0):

more or less pasting [Stephen Henderson's comment from above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639297/arrange-the-data-table-in-r-based-on-clash-of-dates#comment84275009_48639297). @Stephen Henderson feel free to copy this answer, and delete my post, if you want to answer this question.

```
pt1 %>% group_by(patient) %>% arrange(patient, time, handling)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   patient [2]
#>          handling patient       time Sorting
#>             <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <int>
#>  1         A_Form    Moon 2017-02-01       5
#>  2 B_Registration    Moon 2017-02-01      10
#>  3     C_Performa    Moon 2017-02-01      15
#>  4       D_Triage    Moon 2017-02-01      20
#>  5     Operation2    Moon 2017-02-03      25
#>  6       D_Triage     Son 2017-02-01      20
#>  7 B_Registration     Son 2017-02-04      10
#>  8     Operation2     Son 2017-02-04      25
#>  9         A_Form     Son 2017-02-07       5
#> 10     C_Performa     Son 2017-02-07      15
```

In case you don't want to sort on `patient`, you can even remove the `%>% group_by(patient)` if you like,

```
pt1 %>% group_by(patient) %>% arrange(time, handling)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   patient [2]
#>          handling patient       time Sorting
#>             <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <int>
#>  1         A_Form    Moon 2017-02-01       5
#>  2 B_Registration    Moon 2017-02-01      10
#>  3     C_Performa    Moon 2017-02-01      15
#>  4       D_Triage    Moon 2017-02-01      20
#>  5       D_Triage     Son 2017-02-01      20
#>  6     Operation2    Moon 2017-02-03      25
#>  7 B_Registration     Son 2017-02-04      10
#>  8     Operation2     Son 2017-02-04      25
#>  9         A_Form     Son 2017-02-07       5
#> 10     C_Performa     Son 2017-02-07      15
```